# Creating a table in excel based on column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a excel as below:
[image]

For each Sales level3 we have a set of "product family" and a set of "country", now I wish to get a output as:

[image]

Each country to have all product families against it. Tried with Vlookup/Index/Match, however I was not able to get the desired output, I would need the output for all countries and sales level3

Comment: one option is to use MS Access Database and then build basic SELECT queries. Another option is to use Excel database functions. Such functions enable you to query information based on certain criteria e.g. country = "Algeria"

So I would suggest getting started on one of the two options mentioned above, and write back if you need further support

Comment: @Vinod  are you looking for all the product families to be appear for all the countries., if no values means it will not show.

Comment: @Shazu: With your suggestion I got a link: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database/
however i am getting an automation error with this VBA:  rs.Open strSQL, cnn , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

Comment: @Punith: Yes punith am looking for all product families to appear for all countries.

Comment: @Vinod: the best option is MS Access and is very intuitive and easy to use. However, if you really have to do it in Excel then please paste your modified VBA code below and I will have a look and see what is causing the problem

Comment: I am confused by your data: columns A and E have the same heading, but B and F seem to represent different kinds of information, so I am not sure what the relationship is between country and product family in your sample output.  Why is "HOSTWS" above "Algeria" on your output?

Comment: @Shazu: Thanks for your inputs, I was able to resolve the VBA issue, now I got the expected output

Comment: @Choirbean: Its more like a hierarchy, please refer to second screen shot.